# How to use dependency injection in ashx (Autofac, MVC4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, autofac

```
public class AutoCompleteCity : IHttpHandler
{
    public IAutoCompleteRepository AutoCompleteRepository { get; set; }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
}

public static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<AutoCompleteRepository>().As<IAutoCompleteRepository>).SingleInstance();
    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

`AutoCompleteRepository` is registered with SingleInstance, but is always null when calling `ProcessRequest`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you post the relevant registration code? Might be easier to spot the culprit

Comment: Also, try to form your title as a question.

Comment: try also registering `AutoCompleteCity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good. What I suspect is that you are missing in your [`PropertyInjectionModule`](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html) httpModules setup in web.config. The following module setup is required for Autofac to work well with ASP.Net:

```
  <add name="ContainerDisposal" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.ContainerDisposalModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
  <add name="PropertyInjection" type="Autofac.Integration.Web.Forms.PropertyInjectionModule, Autofac.Integration.Web"/>
```

Note: the setup for ASP.Net WebForms integration is described [here](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webforms.html).

Comment: ContainerDisposal and PropertyInjection are not known in Autofac.Integration.Mvc

Comment: @YannickHammens - note that these modules is not sitting in the .Mvc assembly, they are in the Autofac.Integration.Web assembly

Comment: Getting this error now: This module requires that the HttpApplication (Global Application Class) implements IContainerProviderAccessor.

Comment: @YannickHammens - yes, read up on the ASP.Net integration as I mentioned.

Comment: The `Autofac.Web` nuget takes care of the web.config setup, all that's left to do is implement IContainerProviderAccessor

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting your dependencies in constructor, if you want to do properties injection you should enable it with: PropertiesAutowired(), in general using autofac if you want to use property injection you need to enable it with PropertiesAutowired() configuration for class in which you want get the injected property, not in class which you want to inject.

prefered way:

```
public class AutoCompleteCity : IHttpHandler
{
    public IAutoCompleteRepository AutoCompleteRepository { get; set; }
    public AutoCompleteCity(IAutoCompleteRepository autoCompleteRepository) {
        AutoCompleteRepository = autoCompleteRepository;
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
    }
```

}

or try this:

```
public static void RegisterDependencies()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<AutoCompleteRepository>().As<IAutoCompleteRepository>()
           .SingleInstance();

    builder.RegisterType<AutoCompleteCity>()
      .As<IHttpHandler>()
      .PropertiesAutowired(); //<--!!!

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
}
```

EDIT:
look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/autofac/BkY4s4tusUc, to learn how to register IHttpHandler.

Comment: Constructor injection does not work with ASP.Net controlled instances. Autofac does not have a say in how these instances are created. There is only property injection support.

Comment: ...for the same reasons, registering `AutoCompleteCity` in the container makes no sense since it will never be resolved through Autofac.

Comment: I stand corrected. It will require using routes and route handlers, though, and is still not possible with ashx-based handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public class AutoCompleteCity : IHttpHandler
{

 private IAutoCompleteRepository _repo;


public IAutoCompleteRepository Repository
{
   get
   {
       if (_repo==null)
       {
            _repo=AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.RequestLifetimeScope.Resolve<IAutoCompleteRepository>();           
        }
       return _repo;
   }
   set
   {
     if (value!=null) _repo=value;
   }
 }
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
 {
 }
 }
```